# Possible issue with Rep Calculations

Tags: bug, support, reputation

I just now looked at one of the questions posted on the site and the answer I have provided which peeked my curiousity:

[Holidays in US for close relative's funeral in EU?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/259/holidays-in-us-for-close-relatives-funeral-in-eu)

The answer has 3 upvotes and it hasn't been marked as Community Wiki but it appears that I don't receive any reputation for these votes.

Am I the only one that this has happened to or is there an issue that affects more than just me?

Comment: If you look closely, you've also received a badge called "Mortarboard" as the system congratulated you for reaching the daily reputation limit :)

Comment: Well.  IMHO daily rep limit on a private beta site shouldn't exist

Comment: @Karlson ask a question on MSO and request this feature.

Comment: @Dirty-flow I did.  Got pecked and heckled...

Answer (score 7):

It's called reputation cap. You cannot earn more than 200 reputation / day from upvotes. For more information see [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)